# Set MsiPackage's as features

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

I am creating a Wix Installer with wix bootstrapper. Wix setup project gives you the possibility to determine which features to install and which not. I am looking the same thing for MsiPackages on bootstrapper, so I can select which msi packages to install.

```
<Chain>
        <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
        <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
        <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\APP1\Wix1WindowsFormsApplication1.msi"/>
        <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\APP2\Wix2WindowsFormApplication2.msi"/>
</Chain>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @lurker I want an interface where i can select which msi packages to install and which not.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a custom bootstrapper application in which you have PlanPackageBegin event where you can select which msi packages to install.  But this is not easy.

With standard bootstrapper application there is a very limited capability to define checkboxes on the Options dialog and use selection of checkboxes to select which packages to install, as discussed here: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Bootstrapper-Custom-UI-Checkbox-to-customize-install-td7596905.html

Comment: the link is not working. 
@adnand could you share your findings?